# Is there an easy way to transform a tensor (3D array) to a 2D array of the tensor slices as the vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Consider a 3D matrix t of size `d1 x d2 x d3`. Is there a an easy way of making the matrix (2D array) of size `d1d2 x d3`?

so the naive implementation/pseudo-code would be something like:

```
T % d1 x d2 x d3
M % d1d2 x d3
for i=1:d3
    t_slice = t(:,:,i);
    m = reshape(t_slice, [d1d2, 1]); %columns of t_slice are the vector
    M(:,i) = m;
end
```

but it seemed something that should already be implemented or some library in matlab that already does this. Doing this by hand seems a little inefficient and I was suspecting that there was some clever MATLAB trick to do this. Am I right?

Ideally I thought something like:

```
M = reshape(T,[d1d2, d3])
```

would exist, but wasn't sure or couldn't find it yet...

I actually also mean to ask, is it possible to convert that matrix back to its tensor in a nice way in MATLAB?

Comment: Looks like it should work fine. Is there a problem?

Comment: And by "it" I mean the single-line solution at the bottom.

Comment: @beaker it does work, it seems that when I ran that, I did something wrong and when I tried to see why by reading the documentation mis-interpret it and go confused. All is good. Thanks.

Comment: @beaker I actually meant to extend the question...is it possible to convert that matrix back to its tensor in a nice way in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is fine.  What's wrong with what you had in your question at the bottom?

```
M = reshape(T, [d1*d2 d3]);
```

This would unroll each 2D slice in your 3D tensor into a single column and stack all of the columns together into a 2D matrix.  I don't see where your problem lies, other than the fact that you didn't multiply `d1` and `d2` together.  In general, you would want to do this, given `T`:

```
M = reshape(T, [size(T,1)*size(T,2) size(T,3)]);
```

Or, you can let MATLAB infer the amount of columns by doing:

```
M = reshape(T, size(T,1)*size(T,2), []);
```

---

To address your other question, to go back from the converted 2D matrix into its original 3D tensor, just do:

```
T2 = reshape(M, d1, d2, d3);
```

In our case, this would be:

```
T2 = reshape(M, size(T,1), size(T,2), size(T,3));
```

Bear in mind that you must be cognizant of the original dimensions of `T` before doing this.  Remember, `reshape` works by going over column by column and reshaping the matrix to whatever dimensions you see fit.  This will now take each column and convert it back into a 2D slice, then do this for all columns until you get your original 3D matrix back.

To illustrate going back and forth, suppose we have this matrix `T`:

```
>> T = randi(10,3,3,3)

T(:,:,1) =

     9    10     3
    10     7     6
     2     1    10


T(:,:,2) =

    10    10     2
     2     5     5
    10     9    10


T(:,:,3) =

     8     1     7
    10     9     8
     7    10     8
```

To get our unrolled slices so that they fit into columns, use the first line of code above and you you should get a 9 x 3 matrix:

```
>> M = reshape(T, size(T,1)*size(T,2), [])

M =

     9    10     8
    10     2    10
     2    10     7
    10    10     1
     7     5     9
     1     9    10
     3     2     7
     6     5     8
    10    10     8
```

As you can see, each column is a slice from the 3D tensor unrolled into a single vector.  Each column takes every column of a slice and stacks them on top of each other to get a single column.

To go backwards:

```
>> T2 = reshape(M, size(T,1), size(T,2), size(T,3))

T2(:,:,1) =

     9    10     3
    10     7     6
     2     1    10


T2(:,:,2) =

    10    10     2
     2     5     5
    10     9    10


T2(:,:,3) =

     8     1     7
    10     9     8
     7    10     8
```

As you can see, both `T` and `T2` are the same.

Comment: documentation: "reshape(X,M,N) or reshape(X,[M,N]) returns the M-by-N matrix 
    whose elements are taken columnwise from X. An error results 
    if X does not have M*N elements." so I thought it would crash...maybe I should have tried running it. Lets see...

Comment: @Pinocchio - It shouldn't because if each slice is `M x N`, then `reshape` will work perfectly fine.

Comment: I guess ur right, I should have done something wrong the first time I ran it and at the same time interpret the documentation wrongly. Thnx. Can't accept ur answer yet :/

Comment: @Pinocchio - lol no worries.  It happens to all of us.  Accept whenever you're able :)

Comment: I actually meant to extend the question...is it possible to convert that matrix back to its tensor in a nice way in MATLAB?

Comment: @Pinocchio - Yup: `T = reshape(M, d1, d2, d3);`.  Remember, `reshape` works by going over column by column and reshaping the matrix to whatever dimensions you see fit.  This will now take each column and convert it back into a 2D slice, then do this for all columns until you get your original 3D matrix back.  I've also included this in my post to be clear.  I'll add an example soon.

Comment: @Pinocchio - Example added. Have a look.

Comment: @Pinocchio - So did I answer your question?

Comment: give me one sec rayryeng, I will read it in a bit :) thanks for all the help btw!

Comment: Index exceeds matrix dimensions when I ran M = reshape(T, size(T,1)*size(T,2), []);This is what I get:>> M = reshape(T, size(T,1)*size(T,2), [])
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.